# log file is not getting created using JDK logging with Commons-logging

Tags: java, logging, apache-commons-logging

When I run the `TestJcLLoggingService` class log messages are coming to Console but no log file is created, please help me if you know the answer.

two source files are pasted below.

**TestJcLLoggingService.java**

```
package com.amadeus.psp.pasd.logging;

import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
public class TestJCLLoggingService {
    private static Log psp_log = LogFactory.getLog(TestJCLLoggingService.class);
    public static String testJCLLoggingServiceMethod(){
        psp_log.info("start of method testJCLLoggingServiceMethod class TestJCLLoggingService");

        psp_log.info("start of method testJCLLoggingServiceMethod class TestJCLLoggingService");
        return "This is a test string for JCLLogging";

    }

    public static void main(String[] args){

        testJCLLoggingServiceMethod();

    }

}
```

**logging.properties**

```
handlers = java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler, java.util.logging.FileHandler
.level = ALL
com.amadeus.psp.pasd.level=ALL
java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.level = ALL
java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.formatter = java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter


java.util.logging.FileHandler.pattern = %h/java%u.log 
java.util.logging.FileHandler.level=ALL
java.util.logging.FileHandler.limit=50000
java.util.logging.FileHandler.count=1
java.util.logging.FileHandler.formatter=java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter
java.util.logging.FileHandler.append=true
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is answered in a related thread : [Java util logging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/960099/how-to-set-up-java-logging-using-a-properties-file-java-util-logging/1287249#1287249)

Basically you need to set the path of the configuration file (logging.properties) either in java args or in code itself and then look in the right folder. (Default is user home)