# IntelliJ: Adding a dependency doesn't work but adding to classpath under SDK (Project settings) works

Tags: java, intellij-idea, classpath

can anyone help?

I have reading various blogs and it appears to include i18n properties and otherfiles i have to add them as module dependency, choose Jar .. Directories and then chosing "classes" category.

I have done this but i keep getting an error saying that it can't find an XML file. Specfically this

```
admin-sidebar.xml
```

I managed to fix this by adding the 2 directories under Projec Settings, SDK, and adding them to classpath.

but this is annoying that it doesn't work the way in the tutorials.. i must be doing something wrong.

I have to add 2 directories into the class path.

the first directory has about 8 .properties files, these are standard javabundles.

the next directory has the following content

> admin-sidebar.xml METAINF (a directory) mime.types (a file inside the
>   METAINF directory)

Can anyone tell me what i am doing wrong, of course i can leave it the way i have done which seems to fix the issue, but it just feels like i am not doing it right

Any ideas or help?

Thanks in advance

**EDIT**

Here is the project zipped up.

https://docs.google.com/open?id=0ByGL4ug6mtrsdFFNNmtZNXMxV0k

Ok, this is what i am doing, add modules but it doens't work

how it looks when adding, i choose classes

[image]

and this is how it looks when added

[image]

This above doesn't work, but adding it directly too the jdk class path works,  notice its the same 2 dirs.

[image]

The contents of the directory are (in order)

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You either configure it as a library (classpath) entry added to the [module dependencies](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/configuring-module-dependencies-and-libraries.html) or you set up the directory as **Sources** so that these files are automatically added to the classpath (and copied to output according to `Settings` | `Compiler` | `Resource Patterns`).

If this approach doesn't work, please share a sample project with either configuration showing the issue.

See also my reply to the related question: [Add a properties file to IntelliJ's classpath](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3765998/104891).

Comment: Thanks CrazyCoder, i have updated my msg with screenshots and the sample project.   I hope everything is in order. Thanks once again. I know its probably something i am doing wrong.

Comment: Looks like you are adding dependencies to the wrong module (`Broadcast`), while they should be added to a different module (most likely `Openfire_src`).

Comment: sorry crazycode, i did it so fast just to show the example in the screenshots, i have already tried that.. i will it again.. but for sure its the same... check back in 5 mins

Comment: wow! you were right! that was it!. i wonder if i could pick your brains very quickly.. i am a kind of person that needs to know why :-) it worked.. ok.. so basically before it was set to copy but i was running opensrc (correct module), i should never add modules under the classpath where the sdk is right? this is wrong, its hands off, its for the sdk (jdk) only... a big thanks for this, your solved my issues... i suppose it didn't use the class path because it was in broadcast and not the opensrc i was using, of course in the right column i should have accepted the correct module (opensrc)