# How add log4j (for consol) in project (with hibernate and spring)

Tags: java, database, spring, hibernate, log4j

I want to add log4j (for consol) to my tests in project (I use hibernate and spring).
I added log4j.properties in test/resources:

```
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, stdout

log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
```

and write in test class:

```
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
private Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(MyTest.class);

    @Test
    public void test1() {
        logger.info("info test");
        logger.debug("debug test");
    }
```

gradle:

```
testCompile 'log4j:log4j:1.2.17'
```

But I have not this text (`"info test"`) in console, I have in console:

```
13:01:24.626 [main] DEBUG o.h.p.w.spi.MetamodelGraphWalker - Visiting attribute path : maxKeyNumber
13:01:24.626 [main] DEBUG o.h.p.w.spi.MetamodelGraphWalker - Visiting attribute path : updated
13:01:24.626 [main] DEBUG o.h.p.w.spi.MetamodelGraphWalker - Visiting attribute path : credential
13:01:24.626 [main] DEBUG o.h.p.w.spi.MetamodelGraphWalker - Visiting attribute path : aid
13:01:24.626 [main] DEBUG o.h.p.w.spi.MetamodelGraphWalker - Visiting attribute path : cvmConfig
13:01:24.626 [main] DEBUG o.h.p.w.spi.MetamodelGraphWalker - Visiting attribute path : dki
13:01:24.626 [main] DEBUG o.h.p.w.spi.MetamodelGraphWalker - Visiting attribute path : isMsdSupport
13:01:24.627 [main] DEBUG o.h.p.w.spi.MetamodelGraphWalker - Visiting attribute path : serviceCode
```

Comment: Didn't you forget to put the log4j dependency in your pom?

Comment: I use gradle, and I added log4j dependency in build.gradle

Comment: Are you sure it is the right console, you are looking at? Do "System.out.println" outputs end up there ?

Comment: I am sorry, In console I have: 
15:15:56.228 [main] INFO  tests.MyTest - info test

15:15:56.228 [main] DEBUG tests.MyTest - debug test

Comment: But I set just 'INFO' (log4j.rootLogger=INFO, stdout), why I have 'debug' in console?

Answer (score 0):

Can you verify log4j.properties resource is in the classpath and is found at runtime? Usually if you add test/resources folder to the source path in eclipse project, the bin folder should have it (the output folder name can be different, but this file must be on the classpath).

Comment: Maybe you prompt me - how can to verify log4j.properties resource is in the classpath and is found at runtime?
I use intellij idea and I set in structure project test/resource folder as resource.

Comment: A way to check build path is [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3765998/add-a-properties-file-to-intellijs-classpath).  Also search your entire project on disk for log4j.properties. You must find two of them... one in test/resources folder and see where the other one is. If you find only 1 under test/resources, you don't have it on classpath. Now, find where *.class files are going. That is your classpath.

Answer (score 0):

Added log4j.xml file in src folder and change the file location below at place of xyz.log`<!-- FILE Appender -->
    <appender name="FILE" class="org.apache.log4j.FileAppender">
        <param name="File" value="D:\\xyz.log" />
         <param name="MaxFileSize" value="1MB" />
         <param name="MaxBackupIndex" value="100" />
        <param name="Append" value="false" />
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
           <param name="ConversionPattern" value="[%d{dd/MM/yy hh:mm:ss:sss z}] %5p %c{2}: %m%n" />
        </layout>
    </appender`.

>

Comment: Why? OP wants log on console, not in a file.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add console appender to log4j. I have done it with log4j.xml, not with the property file. I hope you can transform this to your log4j.properties file.

```
    <appender name="console" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d - %m%n"/>
    </layout>
</appender>
```

And Finally you need to add this appender to root logger.

```
    <root>
    <priority value="debug"/>
    <appender-ref ref="error"/>
    <appender-ref ref="console"/>
    <appender-ref ref="trace"/>
</root>
```

Hope this helps

Comment: In Propertyfile, this is done with this line: "log4j.rootLogger=INFO, stdout"