# Not able to locate log4j.properties in IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea, properties, log4j

I am not able to locate the file log4j.properties in java using the IntelliJ IDE.
I have tried creating the properties folder resource bundle but nothing. I tried copying everywhere, but looks like I need to add to the classpath or else it won't work.

I also know I can create a File with a custom path and then give this File object to PropertyConfigurator.configure(File file).

But I want to know how to create a property folder in IntelliJ and add it to the classpath. In Eclipse this is very straight forward process, but IDEA I am not able to do. I am using IntelliJ 2016.

Thanks,

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add a properties file to IntelliJ's classpath](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3765998/add-a-properties-file-to-intellijs-classpath) ... the solution may be as simple as telling IntelliJ that the properties file is source code (which would cause it to be included on the classpath).

Comment: I have already tried doing those things but still doesn't work.

Comment: Does the properties file appear in your build output?  If so, then you might be referring to it incorrectly.  If not, then you need to add it to the classpath.