# Listing resources subdirectory in scala NullPointerException

Tags: java, scala

I am trying to list all the files within a subdirectory in my `resources` directory but I am getting a `NullPointerException` because the line

`val testDataDir = getClass.getResource("/data")`

is returning `java.net.URL = null`

Resources structure:

```
/resources
  /data
    file1.txt
    file2.txt
  fileX.txt
```

My code is based off of this blog's code examples: [here](http://fruzenshtein.com/scala-working-with-resources-folders-files/)

This is the code snippet I am using:

```
val testDataDir = getClass.getResource("/data")    
val folder = new File(testDataDir.getPath)
var testDataArr: ListBuffer[String] = new ListBuffer[String]
if (folder.exists && folder.isDirectory) {
  folder.listFiles.toList.foreach(file => testDataArr += file.toString)
}
```

Comment: did you actually create a class named: val ?
What exactly are you trying to get?

Comment: Might be a duplicate of this question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3803326/this-getclass-getclassloader-getresource-and-nullpointerexception

Comment: What version of scala are you using?

Answer (score 2):

1) You can go with **absolute path** `getClass.getResource("/src/main/resources/data/")`

**using scala REPL** from the root of the project, and to load `src/main/resources/fileX.txt`

```
scala> val appConfig = getClass.getResource("/src/main/resources/fileX.txt")
testDataDir: java.net.URL = file:/Users/prayagupd/scala_project/src/main/resources/fileX.txt
```

Or, loading package,

```
scala> val testDataDir = getClass.getResource("/src/main/resources/data")
testDataDir: java.net.URL = file:/Users/prayagupd/scala_project/src/main/resources/data
```

It does not work with filename only inside `src/main/resources`,

```
scala> val testDataDir = getClass.getResource("fileX.txt")
testDataDir: java.net.URL = null
```

**2) Or, you can set your `resources` in classpath(`-cp`),**

```
scala -cp src/main/resources/ TestResources.scala

object TestResources {                                                                                                                                                                     

   def main(args: Array[String]) = {                                                                   
      println("testing resources")                                                                                
      val data = getClass.getResource("/data")                                                           
      println(data)                                                                   
   }                                                                               
}
```

*It does work inside IDE too, as it [loads from compiled version classpath](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3766176/432903)*

```
val resources = getClass.getResource("/data")
file:/Users/prayagupd/scala_project/target/test-classes/data
```