# how to remove newline from java logger api?

Tags: java, logging

Here is my code-

```
Logger log = Logger.getLogger("myApp");
log.info("hola");
```

it displays output as-

```
Mar 16, 2012 8:58:39 PM *packageName* main 
INFO: hola
```

I don't want it to create a newline before "INFO" ... how do I tell logger to do it? I want my output to be like this-

```
Mar 16, 2012 8:58:39 PM *packageName* main INFO: hola
```

Much like syslog format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at how to [configure the Java logging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/960099/how-to-set-up-java-logging-using-a-properties-file-java-util-logging), and the documentation on [how to specify formatting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/logging/SimpleFormatter.html) for `SimpleFormatter`.

Answer (score 1):

Various ways but here is one.  Modify as necessary inside publish().

```
    Logger log = Logger.getLogger("");
    for (Handler handler :log.getHandlers() ) log.removeHandler(handler);
    log = Logger.getLogger("myLogger");
    log.addHandler(new Handler(){
        public void publish(LogRecord record) {
            System.out.println(record.getMessage());
        }
        public void flush() {
        }
        public void close() throws SecurityException {
        }});
    log.info("hola");
```