# jOOQ complains about multiple inheritance of excluded tables

Tags: java, postgresql, jooq

I am getting hundreds of messages like this:

```
Sep 24, 2015 11:21:52 AM org.jooq.tools.JooqLogger info
INFO: Multiple inheritance     : Multiple inheritance is not supported by jOOQ: "other_schema"."some_table" inherits from "other_schema"."parent_a"
Sep 24, 2015 11:21:52 AM org.jooq.tools.JooqLogger info
INFO: Multiple inheritance     : Multiple inheritance is not supported by jOOQ: "other_schema"."some_table" inherits from "other_schema"."parent_b"
```

All of these tables are excluded from generation, and in fact, `other_schema` is not the schema specified in `inputSchema`. Is there a way to suppress these? Ideally tables outside `inputSchema` wouldn't be fetched at all.

This isn't a big deal, but it's cluttering up my log files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be a bug ([#4579](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/4579)). Those messages shouldn't appear when the relevant tables are excluded from the code generation run.

Since you're doing logging via `java.util.logging` ([the default in jOOQ, if log4j or slf4j aren't on the classpath](http://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-execution/logging/)), you can specify a logging configuration file via a JVM flag [as explained in this Stack Overflow question here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/960133/521799). The relevant logger is that of `org.jooq.util.postgres.PostgresDatabase`