# Changing the log level for a selenium node running in docker

Tags: selenium, docker

Our team is deploying a selenium grid using docker. The default log level appears to be set to INFO. I'd like to set it to something higher, SEVERE or turn them completely off. I've made three attempts, but so far, to no effect.

Method One:

From the selenium client, I've tried  to set LoggingPreferences on the RemoteWebDriver within DesiredCapabilities:

```
DesiredCapabilities desiredCapabilities = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
LoggingPreferences logs = new LoggingPreferences();
logs.enable(LogType.BROWSER, Level.SEVERE);
logs.enable(LogType.CLIENT, Level.SEVERE);
ogs.enable(LogType.DRIVER, Level.SEVERE);
logs.enable(LogType.SERVER, Level.SEVERE);
desiredCapabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.LOGGING_PREFS, logs);
desiredCapabilities.setCapability(FirefoxDriver.PROFILE, profile);
WebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL(host:4444/wd/hub"), 
                                           desiredCapabilities);
```

Method 2: I tried to change the profile preferences:

```
FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();

profile.setPreference("webdriver.log.driver", "OFF");
profile.setPreference("webdriver.log.file","/dev/null");
```

Method 3: I tried to modify config.json in the container located in /opt/selenium/config.json:

```
{
  "capabilities": [
    {
      "browserName": "*firefox",
      "maxInstances": 1,
      "seleniumProtocol": "Selenium"
    },
    {
      "browserName": "firefox",
      "maxInstances": 1,
      "seleniumProtocol": "WebDriver"
    }
  ],
  "configuration": {
      "proxy": "org.openqa.grid.selenium.proxy.DefaultRemoteProxy",
      "maxSession": 1,
      "port": 5555,
      "register": true,
      "registerCycle": 5000,
      "logLevel":FATAL
  }
}
```

So far I've been unable to do anything that has altered the logging behavior.

Comment: I did get this to work in a very blunt way... I took selenium-node-firefox as my base image and modified the command that kicks off selenium to re-route standard out to /dev/null.

Would prefer to just increase the log level.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@Scott

The Selenium codebase uses the Java Utils Logger. So maybe you can try passing in a custom logging.properties wherein the log levels are bumped up and see if that helps. [ See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/960099/how-to-set-up-java-logging-using-a-properties-file-java-util-logging) to know a bit more about logging.properties ]

The LoggingPreferences class is mainly used to tweak the log levels that are to be retrieved only for a given session [ atleast that's what I think it is ] and it doesn't alter the logging level of the JVM that the node/grid runs under.

In the case of Selenium server standalone, the log levels can be changed via the JVM argument "selenium.LOGGER.level"

Comment: Thanks, though I'm still having trouble getting this to work... Just getting out of docker completely and trying this:

java -Djava.util.logging.config.file=./logging.properties -jar selenium-server-standalone.jar -role node 

I'm still seeing logs at INFO.

Comment: Scott- I looked through the selenium codebase. If you wanted to turn on logs at WARNING level, then you need to use the JVM argument "selenium.LOGGER.level"

Ex : java -Dselenium.LOGGER.level=WARNING -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.53.0.jar

Please try again using the above mentioned JVM argument.

Comment: Thanks Krishnan, this worked. Next time look at the source code :-).

Answer (score 0):

I realized this already has an accepted answer, but looking at the [readme for selenium grid](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/docker-selenium#se_opts-selenium-configuration-options), it seems there is an **SE_OPTS** environment variable in the docker file where you can pass commandline settings to seleniuim.

There is also a **SE_JAVA_OPTS** variable which is the same but for the JVM.

Usage example shows how to change logging level:

```
SE_OPTS=--log-level FINE
```

I just stuffed this in my `docker-compose.yaml` andand changed `FINE` to `WARNING` and it seems to work. The available log levels are [documented here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/logging/Level.html).