# How to raise the log level when running Selenium server from the command line?

Tags: selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I'm running selenium server via:

```
java -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=chromedriver -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.53.1.jar
```

...and seeing reams of info logs like:

```
14:24:10.876 INFO - Executing: [new session: Capabilities [{rotatable=true, locationContextEnabled=true, loggingPrefs=org.openqa.selenium.logging.LoggingPreferences@4ebd157c, browserName=chrome, javascriptEnabled=true, handlesAlerts=true, requestOrigins={name=webdriverio, version=4.5.2, url=http://webdriver.io}}]])
14:24:10.885 INFO - Creating a new session for Capabilities [{rotatable=true, locationContextEnabled=true, loggingPrefs=org.openqa.selenium.logging.LoggingPreferences@4ebd157c, browserName=chrome, javascriptEnabled=true, handlesAlerts=true, requestOrigins={name=webdriverio, version=4.5.2, url=http://webdriver.io}}]
```

What arguments do I need to pass to show WARNING instead of INFO level?  Failing that, how do I disable it completely? Redirecting stdout and stderr via 2>&1 doesnt seem to get it.

Comment: try this `selenium.LOGGER.level` as cmd argument.i didnt test.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37353002/changing-the-log-level-for-a-selenium-node-running-in-docker

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up redirecting selenium logging to a file, which quieted it down stdout significantly:

```
java -log /tmp/selenium-log -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=chromedriver -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.53.1.jar  &
```

Answer (score 0):

> What arguments do I need to pass to show WARNING instead of INFO level?

Add following additional arguments to your command

-Dwebdriver.log.enabled=true -Dwebdriver.log.file=logs/webdriver.log -Dwebdriver.log.verbosity=verbose

Comment: That writes the logs to a file, but doesnt change the log level.  I'm still seeing INFO level logs like: `1:21:34.284 INFO - Done: [get text: 5 [[ChromeDriver: chrome...`

Comment: Check [this link] (https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/logging)  for more details on this. 

 You could start chromedriver "
chromedriver.exe --verbose --log-path=chromedriver.log"

Comment: This seems not to work with selenium-server-standalone-2.42.2.jar.